# Does chrome sync clicked URLs or only typed URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I often read newsletters with recommended articles that are linked in the email.

I clicked one article on laptop 1 and then when I moved to laptop 2 - both have my chrome logged in and sync enabled.

I checked for `chrome://sync-internals` that both showed `Last sync: just now` and yet I wasn't able to directly open the article URL by typing in a single word from the article title - which does work on laptop 1, the term was "hope" as in the title states "is there still hope for".

I noticed that chrome on laptop 2 did not have this synced and while looking it up I saw that chrome specifically mentions "typed URLs" in their sync settings instead of just URLs.

So looks like it doesn't sync URLs that were clicked from another page!